# HTML5: Baixar conteúdo (script) ao clicar em uma página e executar ele.

Tags: javascript, html5

Como faço para baixar um script que está online automaticamente cada vez que eu clicar para abrir certa página? e adiciona-lo a página

Estou tentando fazer um app e em algumas páginas tem leitura de feeds, mas na hora que compilo com o Visual Studio, o app não carrega o script online (nem a fonte usada)..

Código que estou tentando:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gsmfans.org%2Findex.php%3Ftype%3Drss%3Baction%3D.xml&num=25&desc=1&au=y&date=y&tz=-3&targ=y&utf=y&pc=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Essa URL que está no atributo `src` leva a um arquivo Javascript? **ps:** O atributo `language` está *deprecated* faz tempo. Se estiver usando HTML5 o atributo `type` é desnecessário.

Comment: Você está fazendo preview no próprio aplicativo? Se estiver, sugiro testar no próprio browser.

Comment: Leva ao rss do site que é um javascript, usei uma ferramenta para fazer isso, pois fica mais fácil.. Estou no html5, já tinha retirado, é que eu peguei esse trecho de um projeto anterior...

Comment: Sim, no próprio aplicativo, porque no browser (do pc) funciona, e não tem como testar no browser do smartphone pois não é um dominio de internet.. Daí quando compilo o projeto no VIsual Studio ele não funciona mais esse comando